# Mostrar PrettyPrint JSON en Slim3

Tags: php, api, slim, slim3

Estoy creando una api restful con el framework `Slim3` los datos me los devuelve con json, pero para debugar me gusta más que se muestre la respuesta con un formato más bonito.

en `PHP` puro lo hago usando

```
json_encode($datos, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Tengo lo siguiente

```
$app->get('/ads', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $db = $this->get('db');
    $datos = $db->get('ads');
    return $this->response->withJson($datos);
});
```

Comment: El método `withJson` de la clase [Slim\Http\Response](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Response.php#L318) acepta 3 parámetros. Podrías probar con `return $this->response->withJson($datos, null, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: @amenadiel funciona perfectamente si quieres realizar la respuesta así la puedo cerrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método withJson de la clase [Slim\Http\Response](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Response.php#L318) acepta 3 parámetros:

1. La data que quieres encodear
2. El header con que quieres contestar
3. Las opciones pasa pasarle a la función json_encode.

Por lo anterior, la siguiente combinación

```
return $this->response->withJson($datos, null, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Llevaría a ejecutar

```
json_encode($datos, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Dentro del método